# Simultaneous DMA to user memory

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, dma

Consider this

Thread 1 in user program:

```
buf = malloc(9000);
memset(buf, 0xee, 9000);
read(buf, 9000); //for example gives pages [part of 7, 8, 9, part of 10]
```

Thread 2 in user program:

```
buf = malloc(9000); //for example gives pages [part of 4, 6, 5, part of 7]
memset(buf, 0xee, 9000);
read(buf, 9000);
```

Driver read:

```
get_user_pages();

//build dma sg list from pages
//...

//the platform demands a cachesync
for(all pages) {
    dma_cache_wback_inv();
}

//start dma and wait for it to be done
//...
wait_event_interruptible_timeout(); //blocks calling thread until dma done

for(all pages) {
    if(read) SetPageDirty();
    page_cache_release();
}
```

Note that page 7 is used by both transfers, and that was a big problem sometimes resulting in bad data (0xee is found in the end of one buf). Just to make it clear, the two reads runs on different DMA channels, so they can run simultaneously.

My solution was to page align the buffers in the user program so that 2 driver DMA will never share parts of the same page.

I wonder if there is another solution for this?
I also wonder why exactly this was a big problem.

Comment: This is probably quite platform specific - the requirement to invalidate the cache suggests you're running on an embedded system. Were the two buffers close enough to share a cache line, or are there other limitations in your platform errata?

Comment: Yes it's a ppc440ep, and the buffers are probably close enough. A cache line is 32 bytes, and i have only seen 4-12 bytes broken/unchanged. Can there exist 2 different versions of the same physical memory in the cache? And when i do wback in one thread, can it destroy data for the other? There are no erratas that are not considered as far as i know. But what about get_user_pages? What happens when it returns 2 different versions of the same page? If get_user_pages and page_cache_release from the different threads becomes interleaved.

Comment: I'm not totally clear of what get_user_pages/page_cache_release does, except giving med the physical addresses to the pages. There are no disc cache or anything on this system, only memory and cpu-cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of your embedded processor, and DMA that isn't cache coherent. On high end PowerPC chips this problem goes away.

Your two buffers share a cache line at the point they meet. At the same time that one thread is in the driver writing the cache to RAM, the second thread is still in memset filling the cache line with 0xee.

DMA 1 writes your data to RAM, but the processor still holds a dirty cache line for that data, containing 0xee. When the second thread writes out the cache, it puts the 0xee over the data that came from DMA1.

The solutions are:

1. Cache-align your buffers (highest performance).
2. Use bounce buffers in the kernel driver (most compatible with existing user space code).

The `get_user_pages()` isn't part of the problem here - this is about hardware and timing.

Comment: I think you are right about it beeing a cache issue, but i also think i have seen errors without using memset, because there were no memset before debugging this problem... But maybe reading a buffer after DMA 1 is done, can make the cache read back 0xee into the cache before DMA 2 is done?

Comment: `malloc` will also touch data around the ends of the buffers for heap maintenance. That may be sufficient.

Comment: Yes, this sounds like an explanation.

Comment: Your answer made me think further.. and I realize there may be a 2nd valid explanation for this... when thread one is processing (reading) the data after DMA 1 is done, it will make the cpu read back 0xee perhaps mixed with DMA 2 data into the cache before DMA 2 is done (thus making dma_cache_wback_inv() useless for DMA 2). Because I have seen invalid data just after DMA is done, but then magically it is later correct... The solution is still the same - cache aligning the data (For us it's not a good option to double the memory used, and demand a memcpy).